# How to generate a list of source files compiled for a particular board configuration in u-boot sources?

Tags: makefile, config, u-boot

U-boot being a bootloader targeted at different architecture and SoC's, there are several source files, and only some of them makes it to the final executable for a particular board. For example, in the *arch/* directory, there is one directory per architecture. If the build is for an ARM architecture SoC, only some of the files in *arch/arm/* will be compiled into the executable.

Which of the source files get compiled into the executable depends on the configuration of the build. This configuration is controlled by a file present in configs/ directory. In case of BeagleBone Black, this file is *configs/am335x_boneblack_defconfig*. This file defines several variables, which are used in Makefiles.

A part of the configs/am335x_defconfig is shown below:

```
CONFIG_ARM=y
CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP2PLUS=y
CONFIG_TI_COMMON_CMD_OPTIONS=y
CONFIG_AM33XX=y
CONFIG_DISTRO_DEFAULTS=y
```

The variables defined in these files are later referenced in other Makefiles. For example, the CONFIG_AM33XX variable defined above is referenced in /arch/arm/mach-omap2/am33xx/Makefile as shown below:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_AM33XX)    += clock_am33xx.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TI814X)    += clock_ti814x.o
obj-$(CONFIG_AM43XX)    += clock_am43xx.o

ifneq ($(CONFIG_AM43XX)$(CONFIG_AM33XX),)
obj-y   += clock.o
endif
```

I guess while executing the command

$make am335x_boneblack_defconfig

the value of the variable CONFIG_AM33XX gets replaced in some transient copy of the Makefile, so that the content of the above makefile gets replaced by

obj-y    += clock_am33xx.o

**Figuring out which source files are included in the final executable just by searching for the config variables in all the Makefiles is a tedious task.** 
**I need a way to create a list of source files which gets compiled for a particular config file automatically**. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a clean build and search for all object files:

```
make mrproper
make foo_defconfig
make -j6
find . -name '*.o'
```

You probably want to exclude directories *tools/* and *scripts/*.

Comment: Is there a simple way to collect the associated source files(.o may be generated from an ASM file or a C file) into a separate directory?